# jQuery ajax on IE8 always return error: "Type Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80070005"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii, internet-explorer-8

I has encountered this problem when using jquery ajax on IE8 (not happen in IE9+, Chrome or Firefox). After researching for a while, still cannot figure out what was the problem. 
A bit on the background, the website was built on Yii PHP framework, jQuery version is 1.8.3 (from Yii core). Here are my code:

```
$.ajax ({
    url: url, // url = "/webapp/vote/apicreate"
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {
        video_id : video_id,
        vote_num : vote_num
    },
    success: function(response){
        alert('success'); // for demonstration only
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, err){
       if (typeof console !== "undefined") console.log(textStatus);
    }
}
```

Okay, with this I always received **"Type Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 80070005"**. Both 'readyState' and 'status' are 0. A bit of frustration, cos I neither know what it mean nor how to fix it. Have tried to use the pure javascript solution which yields the same result...

Last thing to note is I'm on a Mac, testing IE8 using Wine. Can it be related somehow ?

Comment: Is there an answer already? I encountered the same problem

Comment: Hey on that I did a quick fix for IE so not exactly is a solution. But if you really wanna test, abandon Wine. Too much trouble..., use https://modern.ie/en-us + virtual box

Answer (score 0):

Use the following steps to troubleshoot:

- Change the `url` value to 127.0.0.1
- Use `alert(response.responseText)` instead of 'success'

Comment: Hi, I tried it online as well as localhost, the same issue happened so i don't think change url to IP works. 
For the ajax, it always go to 'error' callback actually, so no point changing the 'success' callback.

Comment: @NathanDo Is the URL you're posting to http or https?